# less '+&pattern' in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, less-unix

I am trying to use less (in cygwin) with an initial command of &pattern:

```
printf 'A\nB\n' | less '+&B'
```

Give me the text "&/B" at the topleft of my screen, and I have to press
ENTER to do the actual filtering.

I was expecting it to do the filtering right away.

```
(
printf 'A\nB\n' | less '+/B'
Here line B is at top of screen, without the need for pressing ENTER
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf 'A\nB\n' | less '+&B^M'
```

where `^M` is CTRL+v plus RETURN on bash

Comment: If I type printf 'A\nB\n' | less '+&B^M' then ^M becomes part of the search string, and I still have to press ENTER?

Comment: Ah! Got it. Thanks